# Scrolling NSTextView in OSX Today Widget with scrollwheel

Tags: macos, nstextview, nsscrollview, first-responder, today-extension

I have the following view hierarchy in Today Widget app:

- `NSScrollView`
- `NSClipView`
- `NSTextView`

When the text in `NSTextView` is bigger than it's size, I am able to scroll by highlighting text with a mouse, or by using arrow keys.
But when I try to scroll with mouse wheel or trackpad, it does not work. The question is similar to this one: [NSTextView does not scroll when created with NSCollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335956/nstextview-does-not-scroll-when-created-with-nscollectionview), but the `NSTextView` is now being placed on top of bigger srollview of side panel (where Today widgets are).

I think, it may be related with responder chain. The scrollview of `NSTextView` does not even get events, such as:
`- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent` or
`-(void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent *)theEvent`

How can I solve this problem?